# Roleplaying a rogue thief without stereotypical motivations?

Tags: rogue, roleplaying, pathfinder-2e

My group started a Pathfinder 2E campaign at the beginning of the COVID-19 lockdown which was meant to be a throwaway bit of fun on Friday evenings. As time has progressed we've been playing on a such a regular basis and we have reached a point where the disposable nature of my character is feeling pretty thin.

I'm playing a CN Rogue Thief with a Street Urchin background.

We somehow have managed to end up in a position of power, "ruling" a small town of dragon worshipers who hate our guts after we killed the previous Lord.

I'm struggling to come up with reasons for my character to stick around when he has no political aspirations, he isn't getting paid for the work and I would like something which is a bit more nuanced than "so he can steal all the stuff"

Comment: What is your question? Or perhaps more usefully; what kind of answer are you looking for? I'm having a hard time seeing what is being requested and and reads too close to "come up with a bunch of ideas" which is better suited to the unsorted sprawling responses of a traditional forum than in the format of stack site.

Comment: But where are my manners, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: This question could be improved by stating what your character's goals and preferred methods are; just [edit] them in. That way, we know more about what your problem is.

Comment: @TimRasim [Please don't answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/52137). Even on closed questions, it invalidates our closure process.